# Does NeoLoad support load testing for RESTful webservices?

Tags: rest, neoload

I want to use NeoLoad to perform load test on:
1. HTTP traffic
2. REST services

From the NeoLoad site I found that it supports HTTP and SOAP. Can anyone confirm me that using NeoLoad I can perform load testing for REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your interest in NeoLoad. I'm working at Neotys, the company who publishes it. NeoLoad works at the minimum with HTTP and HTTPS. As REST is just a superset to these, you can load test your API with NeoLoad and this with just the standard license, without any extras.

On top of this, if you are using the JSON format, NeoLoad facilitates the handling of the requests and responses by showing you the XML tree and allowing you to use for instance Xpaths expressions in the content extractors. http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/index.html#862.htm#o867

About SOAP, which brings new operations over HTTP(s), NeoLoad has a module to decode the calls. With NeoLoad, you can load test your webservices based on SOAP
http://www.neotys.com/documents/doc/neoload/latest/en/html/index.html#839.htm